# Jquery not running completely in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have written a chrome extension
The manifest file is below

```
     {
  "name": "MWE",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
    } ],
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Make this widget bigger"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The jquery file that i am using is given below

```
  $(".dijitAccordionTitle.dijitAccordionTitle-selected").parent().siblings().css("display","none")
    $('#containerDiv').show().parentsUntil('body').andSelf().siblings().hide();
    $("#dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_0").height($(document).height())
```

I want the jquery to execute after page is loaded successfully.The first line is not executing while it runs successfully in developer tools console.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Your code here
});
```

Comment: No now none of lines are executing:(